# Reference Request: fonts used in Elements of $\infty$-Category Theory?

Tags: fonts, math-fonts

As the title says, I'm trying to find out which fonts are used in Riehl and Verity's [Elements of Infinity Category Theory](https://math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/elements.pdf).

Comment: Those are listed in the PDF file, seems to be Garamind, Asana, Source Code Pro, TeX Gyre heros.

Comment: Would you mind pointing out where in the PDF is this? I've tried searching for those and found nothing. Maybe I'm doing something wrong :/

Comment: The meta data. Most standalone PDF viewers can list the documents meta data (not sure if PDFs shown in browsers does). There are also external tools like `pdffonts` (which I used here after downloading the PDF). Note that in some cases the font names are scrambled, not really the case here.

Comment: That's great, many thanks! Appreciated